# Existe um parâmetro a mais para o comando script do linux para que os caracteres sejam gravados com o encoding correto?

Tags: linux, script, codificação-de-caracteres, terminal

Ao usar o comando **script** nomearquivo.txt passa a ser gravado no aquivo criado tudo que é gerado no terminal, porém ao salvar, o texto fica encodificado em vários pontos, pontos que eu precisava ler por um outro projeto que estou trabalhando.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**atenção**: o exemplo específico da pergunta não é um problema de encoding - esta resposta é para este exemplo. Para problemas de encoding ver a respota do @LEo)

No caso, não é um problema de encoding:
Os caracteres que você está vendo como quadradinhos são o caractere "ESC" (código ASCII 27/0x1b/033 - exatamente o que é gerado pela tecla com o mesmo nome)

O que acontece é que no terminal, esse caractere é usado como prefixo para as [sequências ANSI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI), que permitem que o texto no terminal apareça colorido, em negrito, ou até mesmo que o cursor seja reposicionado, etc...

Quando essas sequências são mandadas para o terminal, o programa de terminal "consome" o ESC e os demais caracteres da sequencia, e muda a cor, etc... No entanto, quando são mandados para um arquivo, os caracteres são gravados como chegam, na integra.

Se você mandar imprimir esse arquivo gerado no terminal (`cat nomearquivo.txt`), vai ver que ele não só fica legível, mas todo o texto que foi gerado colorido pelos comandos originais vai aparecer colorido no terminal. O editor de textos que você está usando nao reconhece as sequências (na verdade, não conheço nenhum que use as sequências ANSI para permitir ediçao de arquivos .txt com cores) - e elas são exibidas na integra.

Todas as mais comuns delas tem o formato de "ESC[<;numero>..." (No caso o "abre colchete" `[` é literal, esse caractere mesmo, não uma representação de um trecho opcional).

Isso permite que seja criada uma expressão regular que possa filtrar essas sequências e deixar só o texto.  Note que outros caracteres de controle, como "\x08" (backspace) ou "\x0d" (carreiage return) ainda podem ficar - essas sequências são parecidas com as ANSI, e são usadas para voltar o cursor na mesma linha, para, por exemplo, atualizar barras ou porcentagens de progresso sem mudar de linha.

Dito isso, o comando abaixo pode ser usado direto no temrminal para filtrar as sequências ANSI. (Usei Python em vez de `sed`  mais curto um pouco nesses casos, por que não sei representar o caracter "ESC" na linha de comando para o `sed` - em Python a expressão regular fica dentro de uma string, e qualquer caractere pode ser representado usando `\x` ou `\u` para escape):

```
python3 -c "import re;print(re.sub(r'\x1b+\[[\d;]*?[a-zA-Z]', '', open('nomearquivo.txt').read()))" > arquivo_corrigido.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Um programa está escrevendo um arquivo usando uma determinada codificação e outro programa está lendo usando outra codificação. Não existe marcação no arquivo para indicar qual o tipo de codificação que foi utilizada. O que é possível fazer é um chute educado. Utilize o `file` para verificar qual é a codificação do arquivo gerado. Exemplo:

```
$ file 001.txt 
001.txt: ASCII text
$ file 002.txt 
002.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

O programa que irá ler o arquivo deve ler usando a codificação em que o arquivo foi escrito. Suponha que seu arquivo tenho sido escrito usando UTF-8 e seu programa está lendo usando a codificação ISO 8859-1. Você pode converter de uma codificação para a outra usando o `iconv`.

```
$ iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO8859-1 002.txt > 002_iso.txt
$ file 002_iso.txt 
002_iso.txt: ISO-8859 text
```

Dependendo do caso pode ser necessário utilizar a opção `TRANSLIT`, quando um caractere não pode ser representado na codificação alvo, utilizar esta opção fará com esquetes caracteres sejam mapeados nos caracteres visualmente mais próximos.

```
$ iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO8859-1//TRANSLIT 002.txt > 002_iso.txt
```

Comment: Os conceitos e comandos que você coloca nessa resposta estão bem legais - mas o problema dessa questão em particular não tem a ver com encoding - e sim, com inclusão de sequências ANSI no arquivo.

Essa resposta no entanto pode ser bem legal para mais pessoas chegando aqui - se você adicionar uma nota que nesse caso específico o problema não era encoding, essa resposta poderia ajudar ainda mais gente!